# IKVM + Visual Studio 2010 (VS2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ikvm

I'm trying to upgrade my Visual Studio 2005 IKVM project / solution to use Visual Studio 2010.

My IKVM project compiles and runs just fine using VS 2005.

However, after I upgrade the project to use VS 2010, when I try to Rebuild Solution, I get the following error in VS 2010:

"IKVM.AWT.WinForms.dll" or one of its dependencies requires a later version of the .NET Framework than the one specified in the project.  You can change the .NET Framework target by clicking Properties on the Project menu and then selecting a new target in the .NET Framework dropdown box

I'd appreciate any assistance as I'm not a seasoned .NET or VS developer.

I have checked the Project Properties, and I am still targeting .net 2.0(as previously targeted from VS 2005).

Thanks